# What does "$\max\{m,n\}$" mean (eg, when $m$ and $n$ are degrees of polynomials)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, notation

I was reading a mathematics book, and I found if $f(X)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, and $g(X)$ is a polynomial of degree $m$, then $f(X)\pm g(X)$ is a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $\max\{m,n\}$.

> What does the notation "$\max\{m,n\}$"  mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_and_minimal_elements

Comment: Define $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$. Let $f(x)=x^2+2$ and $g(x)=x^4+3x^3+2x+7$. What is the degree of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$? What is the degree of $h(x)$? What can you conclude from this?

Comment: $\max\{m, n\}$ is simply whichever of the two numbers is bigger. For example $\max\{3, 4\} = 4$.

Comment: I think the name is rather intuitive, one can even guess what it means just by looking at it.

Comment: Further, degree of $h(x)=f(x)\pm g(x)$ should be *less than or equal to* $\mathrm{max}\{m,n\}$. Example: $f(x)=-x^4+x^3$ and $g(x)=x^4+x^3$

Comment: @MattiP. it's only intuitive if you are a native English speaker. Perhaps the OP is not?

Comment: "one can even guess what it means just by looking at it"  Well, That's certainly a good way to learn mathematics!  If you don't know something just assume and make up a meaning but for goodness sake, never ask a question.  What could possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: $\max\{m,\,n\}$ is the maximum of $m$ and $n$, i.e. $m$ if $m\ge n$ or $n$ otherwise.

Long answer: In general $\max S$ is the maximum element of the set $S$, if that maximum exists. A $2$-element set of polynomial degrees (which are non-negative integers or, in the case of the zero polynomial, $-\infty$ in some conventions) denoted $\{m,\,n\}$ certainly has such a maximum; indeed, any finite set of extended real numbers does. So $\max\{m,\,n\}$ is $m$ if $m\ge n$, or $n$ otherwise.